# Not getting RAILS ActiveRecord::Relation returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am running RAILS 3.0.9, and for the life of me, I can not get RAILS to do the new lazy loading.

My gemfile is:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.9'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'nifty-generators', '>= 0.4.6'
gem 'mocha', :group => :test
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'devise', '1.1.rc0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.3'
```

And if I do:

```
Period.where("id=1")
```

I get:

```
[#<Period id: 1, start: "2011-07-06", end: "2011-07-13", created_at: "2011-07-06 23:01:46", updated_at: "2011-07-06 23:01:46"]
```

I really need it to do the ActiveRecord::Relation thing instead! Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Try this: `p = Period.where("id=1")` then `p.class`.  What do you get?

Comment: ahh it is a ActiveRecord::Relation!

Comment: Ok, I guess that is a good sign, I need to figure out why my .includes(:vacations) isn't adding anything to the resultset

Comment: Btw, the reason the query is executing is because IRB does an inspect on the object. Found that in this thread: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/296738#956559

Comment: Brian, can you please add this as an answer, and Ward, can you please accept that answer once Brian adds it, so this question can be marked as answered?

Comment: Yeah, Brian, go ahead and add the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the `ActiveRecord::Relation` thing.

```
foo = Period.where("id=1") # does AR::Relation thing
foo.select( :start ) # does AR::Relation thing

p foo.to_a # Does SQL cmd thing cuz u forced AR::Relation thing to SQL
```

You should only see your start column reported.

An `ActiveRecord::Relation` doesn't evaluate until forced to... like you want it to print values.